# Passing a query string via react-router

Tags: reactjs, query-string, react-router

Hello I am trying to pass information via a query string through react-router but i can not access it. I believe i followed the steps correctly but still nothing.

```
var UserContainer = React.createClass({
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
},
getInitialState: function() {
    return{
        id: this.props.data.id,
        username: this.props.data.username,
        html_url: this.props.data.html_url,
        avatar_url: this.props.data.avatar_url
    }
},
handleUserClick: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = this.state.id;
    var username = this.state.username;
    var html_url = this.state.html_url;
    var avatar_url = this.state.avatar_url;

    this.context.router.push({
        pathname: '/user',
        query: {
            id: id,
            username: username,
            html_url: html_url,
            avatar_url: avatar_url
        }
    });
},

//ROUTED TO THIS COMPONENT 

var React = require('react');

var UserShowView = React.createClass({
contextTypes: {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
},
componentDidMount: function() {
    console.log(this.props.location.query)
},
render: function() {
    return(
        <div>
            Hello
        </div>
    )
}
});

// REACT_ROUTER

var React = require('react');
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var hashHistory = ReactRouter.hashHistory;
var IndexRoute = ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

var UsersIndexContainer = require('../containers/UsersIndexContainer');
var UserShowContainer = require('../containers/UserShowContainer');

var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={UsersIndexContainer} />
    <Route path='user' component={UserShowContainer} />
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

I keep getting this error

[image: error]

But as you can see the query string exists

[image]

Comment: Can you show your router config? Is `UserShowView` a direct child of `Route` element?

Comment: ok two more questions: a) what version of react-router and b) have you tried with `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory` ?

Comment: i just tried switching over. same thing.

Comment: @AyazUddin did the answer below help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an issue with your Router configuration. Instead of declaring "/" and "user" at the same level, you want do embed "user" inside "/" like below:

```
var routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={UsersIndexContainer}>
        <Route path='user' component={UserShowContainer} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
);
```

Give this a try and let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hey kumar. so i tried using the code you provided and now i get the query string but the UserShowView component doesn't render anymore.

Comment: @AyazUddin Some of the real code is missing so it's difficult to help without it. UserShowView, UserShowContainer, UserContainer are all terms used, but can't see how they are related via code. But given your original question around query params is answered, you might want to consider selecting this as an answer and start a new thread with your other question (and relevant code).